# Display text during drag & drop

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop

Our PO wants to display the text that is dragged between two list boxes.
I did not find any clue how to do this on a windows form out of the box.
I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5f33842b-2634-49cb-8b43-5e73e8fbbaee/show-dragged-text-while-dragging-in-vbnet-2008?forum=vbgeneral) article, but it operates with an extra label on the form. Is this really the best and only option?

Comment: Neither of the first 2 answers in the forum use labels, they just use `SelectedItem.ToString`?

Comment: The DragMessage object is a label control.

Comment: Never tried it hence the comment rather than an answer but there is an article on [Code Project - Text Cursor (xCursor)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32213/Text-Cursor-xCursor) on it.

Comment: Oh, my bad, missed that bit. That's a pretty simple and effective way of doing it - What's wrong with doing it that way?

Comment: @OSKM: Thank you, it works, so you can put it as answer :) But I still cannot believe that this must be so complicated.

Comment: @David: I was hoping that there is a property built in the standard drag&drop process. Also, maybe I did something wrong, but I could not make the label move based on those codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above there is an example on [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32213/Text-Cursor-xCursor), I cant take any credit except being able to locate it on a search, all credit due to Elkay on Code Project.

Below is the copied and pasted code in case the link breaks in the future.

```
Dim myCursor As TextCursor.xCursor = New TextCursor.xCursor
myCursor.CursorText = "This is a test cursor"
Me.Cursor = myCursor.GetCursor
Private _Dragging As Boolean        ' Indicates that Dragging has begun
Private _DragSource As Integer = 0      ' The source of the drag

' Here's my custom cursor
Private myCursor As TextCursor.xCursor = New TextCursor.xCursor

''' <summary>
''' Begin our Dragging - setup a few cursor properties
''' </summary>
Private Sub DragLabel_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DragLabel.MouseDown
    _Dragging = True

    myCursor.Shrinkage = 1
    myCursor.Fade = True
    myCursor.Font = DragLabel.Font
    myCursor.CursorText = DragLabel.Text

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' If dragging has begun, fire off the dragdrop and stuff the Object
''' </summary>
Private Sub DragLabel_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DragLabel.MouseMove
    If _Dragging Then
        _DragSource = 1
        DragLabel.DoDragDrop(DragLabel.Text, DragDropEffects.Copy)
    End If
    _Dragging = False
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' If you don't do this, you'll get the standard "You can't drop here" cursor
''' </summary>
Private Sub DragLabel_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DragLabel.DragOver
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' This bad boy is DragDrop UI's Golden Child.  
''' This will fire during the dragging operation
''' (once the DoDragDrop method has been started) and allow you to trap while dragging
'''
''' In the case of this Demo - I'm checking to see if we have a valid drop location:
''' we'll have both an effect AND a true Copy condition set.
''' </summary>
Private Sub DragLabel_GiveFeedback(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.GiveFeedbackEventArgs) Handles DragLabel.GiveFeedback
    e.UseDefaultCursors = False
    If ((e.Effect And DragDropEffects.Copy) = DragDropEffects.Copy) Then
        myCursor.GoodDrop = TextCursors.xCursor.DropValid.GoodDrop
        Cursor.Current = myCursor.GetCursor
    Else
        myCursor.GoodDrop = TextCursors.xCursor.DropValid.BadDrop
        Cursor.Current = myCursor.GetCursor
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Let the ap know we're over a good drop location
''' Share that knowledge with the User by changing our Drag Cursor and 
''' alter the drop control's bg color
''' </summary>
Private Sub DropLabel_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DropLabel.DragOver
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Perform the drop - if anyone knows a more intelligent way to determine 
''' WHERE the drag CAME FROM
''' I would love to hear about it!
''' </summary>
Private Sub DropLabel_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DropLabel.DragDrop
    If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.String))) Then
        Dim item As Object = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(System.String)), _
                                System.Object)
        If _DragSource = 2 Then
            DropLabel.Font = AnotherDrag.Font
        Else
            DropLabel.Font = DragLabel.Font
        End If
        DropLabel.Text = item.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I will keep it as an answer, because it does, what it promises, but there is an unexpected side-effect of this solution: my listbox, that was the source, behaves strange after the drag&drop: The list is not redrawn after the scrolling. The scrollbar works, I can still go down, select, drag&drop the last item, (and see the title during drag), only I don't see the scrolled item and the selection inside the list.